# SQL count distinct over partition by cumulatively

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am using AWS Athena (Presto based) and I have this table named `base`:

| id | category | year | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2021 | 6 |
| 1 | b | 2022 | 8 |
| 1 | a | 2022 | 11 |
| 2 | a | 2022 | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2022 | 4 |
| 2 | b | 2022 | 6 |

I would like to craft a query that counts the distinct values of the categories per id, cumulatively per month and year, but retaining the original columns:

| id | category | year | month | sumC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2021 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | b | 2022 | 8 | 2 |
| 1 | a | 2022 | 11 | 2 |
| 2 | a | 2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2022 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | b | 2022 | 6 | 2 |

I've tried doing the following query with no success:

```sql
SELECT id, 
       category, 
       year, 
       month, 
       COUNT(category) OVER (PARTITION BY id, ORDER BY year, month) AS sumC FROM base;
```

This results in `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3` which is not what I'm looking for. I'd rather need something like a `COUNT(DISTINCT)` inside a window function, though it's not supported as a construct.

I also tried the `DENSE_RANK` trick:

```sql
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY category) 
+ DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY category) 
- 1 as sumC
```

Though, because there is no ordering between `year` and `month`, it just results in `2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you share a bigger sample from your data, with the updated expected ranking?

Comment: @lemon just edited with a second id

Comment: I did not understand the logic behind sumC column. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @shantanuo id=1 has 1 distinct category as of 2021/06 (therefore sumC is 1), then has 2 distinct categories as of 2022/08 (therefore sumC is 2), and still has 2 distinct categories as of 2022/11 (therefore sumC is still 2). what i wanted was a cumulative sum of distinct categories per id over time

Comment: You have mentioned 2 distinct categories as of 2022/08, but I see only 1 row for 2022/08

Comment: @shantanuo the 2nd distinct category is accumulated from the previous rows (2021/06), i need to count and keep track of all distinct categories as of the recent date year/month column

Comment: So if you have a table like this... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e7f3d/1 You need output like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5436b2/1 ?

Comment: @shantanuo yes that's exactly right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is

- creating a new column that will contain when each "*category*" is seen for the first time (partitioning on "*id*", "*category*" and ordering on "*year*", "*month*")
- computing a running sum over this column, with the same partition

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                         PARTITION BY id, category
                         ORDER     BY year, month) = 1
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
           END AS rn1
    FROM base
    ORDER BY id, 
             year_, 
             month_
)
SELECT id,
       category,
       year_,
       month_,
       SUM(rn1) OVER(
            PARTITION BY id
            ORDER     BY year, month 
       ) AS sumC
FROM cte
```